# PHP crashing when loading "RRD Graphs" page on pfSense

Tags: pfsense

When attempting to visit the **Status** > **RRD Graphs** page of pfSense, I am greeted with a blank page...  Most likely due to PHP being unable to complete the request...

I am unsure how to repair this.  On Linux I would usually run something akin to the following to discover the problem, but I can't do this on pfSense (AFAIK):

```
su -l apache -c 'strace php /usr/local/www/status_rrd_graph.php'
```

**Any theories?**

Just to demonstrate how little is returned by PHP:

```
$ wget https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/status_rrd_graph.php --no-check-certificate -O -
--2012-07-20 23:43:06--  https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/status_rrd_graph.php
Resolving XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)... 10.0.0.1
Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)|10.0.0.1|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's certificate, issued by `/C=US/ST=Somewhere/L=Somecity/O=CompanyName/OU=Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)/CN=Common Name (eg, YOUR name)/emailAddress=Email Address':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
    WARNING: certificate common name `Common Name (eg, YOUR name)' doesn't match requested host name `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

    [ <=>                                   ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-07-20 23:43:06 (0.00 B/s) - written to stdout [0/0]
```

Comment: It's returning a `200` code so it has at least output errors before crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, first I've heard of that happening. A quick fix should be to apply the update for the version you're already running, which will basically reinstall the system (overwrites all the system's files at least).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work...  I applied the update image found here: http://files.chi.pfsense.org/mirror/updates/pfSense-Full-Update-2.0.1-RELEASE-i386.tgz, using the web UI (System > Firmware > Manual Update).  And after bit of downtime, the RRD screen is still unavailable...

Comment: Never mind, that was a false-negative.  The empty page was cached, after clearing the cache, everything works on the RRD Graphs page... Thank you!